# Alert in php and Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am with a code where the user connects using his username and password and what I would like to do is that once he is logged in, he will see an alert message where it says:

"Welcome + username +"

I have tried to do it in this way but it is not possible:

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
    <script> alert ("Welcome" . <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>)</script>
```

The alert appears but not with the message I want but with 'undefined'

However, if I don’t put an alert but only a message with the corresponding username, it appears correct:

```
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: `alert('Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>');`

Comment: When debugging, don't skip from PHP to rendered output in the browser. Look at the JavaScript source code you are generating. Think about what it means.

Comment: @NoLifeKing — Danger! You are failing to escape special characters which risks breaking the JS and XSS.

Comment: @Quentin I know. I just made it lazy, to be more like OP had it. (Which is a bad call)

Comment: It should probably be like `alert('Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>');`

Comment: **Never** forget the charset param in the htmlentities function @NoLifeKing ... " encoding

    An optional argument defining the encoding used when converting characters.

    If omitted, the default value of the encoding varies depending on the PHP version in use. In PHP 5.6 and later, the default_charset configuration option is used as the default value. PHP 5.4 and 5.5 will use UTF-8 as the default. Earlier versions of PHP use ISO-8859-1. " Also incorrect charset encoding might cause encoding bypasses

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now it works as I wanted to.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was not aware of that parameter actually. :)

Comment: "I was not aware of that parameter actually." @NoLifeKing Really it's a must know for PHP security

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [PHP concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) inside your JavaScript, you should directly write the username string in the welcome string:

```
<script> alert("Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>")</script>
```

To concatenate strings in JavaScript you should use `+`, but this is not useful in your case.
Also note that this won't be secured and you should sanitize the username to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! :D

Comment: @galep keep in mind that this "solution" still keeps you open for possible cross site scripting attacks.. Never trust the SESSION array to be safe in PHP.